# Updating Google Calendar - Fatal error: Call to undefined function dateTime()

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update Google Calendar using the PHP API. I have successfully been able to create Google Calendar Events and automatically get the ID for the event, but when I try and update the event, I get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dateTime() in public_html/googleapi/calendarupdate.php on line 45. It is referring to the line:

```
$event->setStart.dateTime($startdatetime);
```

Here is my current PHP Code for the error:

```
    <?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$summary = $_POST["summary"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$startdatetime = $_POST["startdatetime"];
$enddatetime = $_POST["enddatetime"];
$clientemail = $_POST["clientemail"];
$privatekey = $_POST["privatekey"];
$useremail = $_POST["useremail"];
$calendarid = $_POST["calendarid"];



$client_email = $clientemail;
$private_key = file_get_contents($privatekey);
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$user_to_impersonate = $useremail;
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key,
    'notasecret',                                 // Default P12 password
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
    $user_to_impersonate
);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = $service->events->get($useremail, $calendarid);
$event->setSummary($summary);
$event->setLocation($location);
$event->setStart.dateTime($startdatetime);
$event->setStart.timeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setEnd.dateTime($enddatetime);
$event->setEnd.timeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setDescription($description);

$updatedEvent = $service->events->update($useremail, $event->getId(), $event);

echo json_encode($updatedEvent);
```

My PHP code is based off of Google's API Documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).

Comment: set start date is a method you need to pass it a date $event->setStart($date);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I actually managed to figure it out. I just had to change the line:

```
$event->setStart.dateTime($startdatetime);
```

To This:

```
$event->start->setDateTime($startdatetime);
```

I do the same general thing for the end datetime, except where it says start, I just put end. Just tested it and it worked perfectly. The site that helped me out can be found [here](https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime.html).